# Change edittext backgroundTint Color

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my editext, i want to change bottom line color of edittext. i use android:backgroundTint but its only work in API 21 and above it.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/edittintcolor"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
                android:hint="  Password"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/edittintcolor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/edittintcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:typeface="serif" />
```

I want to change this color using XML or style not in java code

Comment: Dude, android:backgroundTint is XML?? Isn't it?

Comment: Are you new in android or what.? It's edittext property.

Comment: I want to change edittext tint color. I amd using android:backgroundTint="@color/edittintcolor" property to chnage color but its only work in API 21 or its above.

Comment: You can change the 'active' color of the line by using the `colorAccent` style item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bg.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FDEEF4" />
     <corners
          android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#F9966B" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bd=g"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable xml for your edittext background.. Use this following code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
                <!-- color of edittext line -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set that drawable xml as your edittext background. :)

Comment: I dont wont drawable.Can i change this using style .?

Answer (score 0):

use command like below in edit text

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

then proceed with below code inside drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FDEEF4" />
 <corners
      android:radius="15dp" />
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#F9966B" />
```

## EDEEF4 represents the tint color

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve by using two ways,
Method 1:
We can design background image using selector drawable,

create backgroundEditText.xml in drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />

<item
    android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />

<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />

<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
```

textfield_pressed.9.png
[![textfield_pressed.9][4]][4]

textfield_selected.9.png
[![textfield_selected.9][5]][5]

We need to set backgroundEditText for EditText in layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit1_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[![Final Output  ][6]][6]

Method 2:
Using android.support.v4 support library, we can give backward compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this site](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate your own `EditText` style.

Generate `drawable` and set it as background, like:

```
android:background="@drawable/generated_theme_edit_text"
```